# acces global mutex/semaphore from user application without admin rights

Tags: c#, ipc, mutex, semaphore

I'm trying to get Process A to send a array towards Process B and figured I would do this through IPC. I've managed to get everything working until the point where they have to acces the same Memory mapped file.

After reading upon different ways to do this I found mutexes and semaphores to best the best way without relying on 3rd party software. But the main thing is that Process A is an application that cannot be run with admin rights, but Process B is a windows service running in the local system enviroment. So I tried creating global mutexes and semaphores but they dont seem to cut it. because these require admin rights to acces from my user application.

So how would one create a mutex or semaphore for this kind of situation?

*I apologize in advance for my english and question format(first time poster).*

Comment: You could place parts of Process A which should use the mutex into Process B, and expose it as a public method? Your english is fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Named mutex permission access security:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.mutexsecurity(v=vs.110).aspx

Access Control for you named mutex
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the links, I've stumbled upon this myself already and it seems to be the solution indeed, I will mark your answer as the correct one for now.

Comment: Stumbling across this in attempting to lock down global mutexes on Linux, having trouble finding any details